# Force exponent in scientific format r

Tags: r

I'm sure this will be a duplicate but I can't for the life of me find the right combination of words to type into google to get an answer to this. I want to fix the exponent of some scientific numbers so its always "e-3" irrespective of the number. Example:

```
a <- c(1000, 10000, 100000)
```

Gives 1e3, 1e4, 1e5. I would like the exponent to be fixed at "3":

```
b <- c("1e3", "10e3", "100e3")
```

I've looked at this (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/formatc.html) and tried this:

```
c <- format(a, scientific = 3)
```

But that's no good. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `b` be like `c("1e3", "10e3", "100e3")` from your explanation?

Comment: yes, sorry terrible maths on my behalf there. But even so you go the gist and your answer is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there's no built-in way to fix exponent scale. But you can write your own simple function to generate desired output:

```
#suppress scientific output
options(scipen=1000)
fixexp=function(x) paste(x/1000, "e3",sep = "")
a=c(10.42342, 2000.345, 1000000.766666)

> fixexp(a)
[1] "0.01042342e3"     "2.000345e3"       "1000.000766666e3"
```

Comment: Yes sorry pascal, my maths wasn't correct (see cyberj0g comment). My brain is fried from starting at numbers.